# How to iterate over and test different child elements within an element in cypress?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, automated-tests, cypress

So, I have the elements in the following structure:

```html
<div class="MuiBox-root" data-testid="all-events">
  <ul ....>
    <div class="MuiBox-root" data-testid="event">
    <div class="MuiBox-root" data-testid="event">
    <div class="MuiBox-root" data-testid="event">
```

Now, within each **event** element is the following structure:

```html
 <div class="MuiBox-root" data-testid="event">
  <li .....>
    <div class="MuiBox-root ....." data-testid="event-status">
      <div> Text Value </div>
    <div class="MuiBox-root ....." data-testid="event-name">
```

So, what I want to test is that if the element **event-status** is say completed or active, then the element **event-name** will be present. So the approach that I am using is as follows:

```
cy.get("[data-testid='events']").its("length").then((numEvents) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < numEvents; i++) {
    cy.get("[data-testid='event-status']").each((status, index) => {
      if (index === i) {
        if (isEventActive(status)) {
          cy.get("[data-testid='event-name']").each((name, index) => {
            if (index === i) {
              cy.get(name).should("have.text", "some value");
            }
          });
        } else {
            cy.get("[data-testid='event-name']").each((name, index) => {
            if (index === i) {
              cy.get(name).should("not.exist");
            }
          });
        }
      }
    });
  }
});
```

The above code is working to test what I want to test out but it is incredibly messy and any simpler approaches are welcome.

Comment: You can replace that `index === 0` check with something more flexible like `if (event-status === 'condition')`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Convert the for loop to an `.each()`. Using `.within()` on the event will allow internal `get` commands to be specific to the event, and eliminate the need to check index values.

```js
cy.get("[data-testid='events']").each($event=> { 
  cy.wrap($event).within(() => {
    cy.get("[data-testid='event-status']").each($status => {
      if (isEventActive($status)) {
        cy.get("[data-testid='event-name']").should("have.text", "some value");
      }) else {
        cy.get("[data-testid='event-name']").should("not.exist")
      })
    })
  })
});
```

Maybe this will also work. Uses closure to get the two inner elements ($status and $name) into a ternary expression, and uses `.should("satisfy", callbackFn)` to do an either/or check.

```js
cy.get("[data-testid='events']").each($event => { 
  cy.wrap($event).find("[data-testid='event-status']").then($status => {
    cy.wrap($event).find("[data-testid='event-name']")
      .should("satisfy", $name => isEventActive($status)  
        ? $name.text() === "some value"
        : $name.length === 0;
      );
    })
  })
});
```